# Regex for matching addresses

Tags: regex

I need a pattern that checks for the presence of a US street address or PO Box. The part I don't know how to do is specifying that the string must begin with either a number up to 6 characters or any combination of PO Box such as `(PO BOX|P.O. Box|BOX)`. How do I combine this non-literal with a literal list which can begin anywhere within a wider string?

Thank you

I can do something like this: `^\d{1,6}\s\w+` but I am at a loss how to add the list of literals to it

Comment: Editing your question to include several examples will make it easier for people to properly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I combine this non-literal with a literal list which can begin
> anywhere within a wider string?

```
^(?:\d{1,6}|\b(?:PO BOX|P\.O\. Box|BOX)\b)\s+\d{1,5}\s+\w+.*$
```

Should work.

Comment: `(?:(?:PO )?BOX|P\.O\. Box)` Could be used to use as a 2-in-1